# Not able to run netsh command in Win XP machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cmd, windows-xp, netsh

I want to `Reserve the port` and `port binding` with programmatically with the following code:

```
private void PortReserve()
{
  try
   {
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new           
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.Arguments = @"/c netsh http add urlacl url=https://127.0.0.1:8083/ user=EVERYONE";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw ex;
    }}
```

For port Binding:
Replace the parameter of `startInfo.Arguments` with `@"/c netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:8083 certhash=df03c4b0b32f3302a3b70abe6b5dfd864d0986a5 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-CCBBCCDDEEFF} clientcertnegotiation=enable";`

Above commands are working perfectly in win `7` , `win servers` and `8` machine but when it comes to `Win xp` It started to throw an error in `CMD`:
 `The following command was not found http add urlacl url=https://127.0.0.1:8083 user=Everyone`

I check the certificate which is successfully imported in `mmc` in all `machine`.

What should i do in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acording to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms733791%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can't use netsh for that with xp.

> If you are running Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP, use the
>   HttpCfg.exe tool. With Windows Server 2003 this tool is installed.
>   With Windows XP, you can download the tool at Windows XP Service Pack
>   2 Support Tools. For more information, see Httpcfg Overview. The
>   Windows Support Tools documentation explains the syntax for the
>   Httpcfg.exe tool.